# Gradient Layer over a CustomImageView

Tags: ios, swift, frontend, cagradientlayer

This is my first time trying to apply a gradient layer to a CustomImageView, and to do that within a UICollectionViewCell, I decided to create the following function:

```
func configureGradientOverlay() {
    
    let maskedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.5, width: 400, height: 400))
    maskedView.backgroundColor = .black

    let gradientMaskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientMaskLayer.frame = maskedView.bounds
    gradientMaskLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
    gradientMaskLayer.locations = [0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.99]

    maskedView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
    postImageView.addSubview(maskedView)   
}
```

This seems to do the trick in applying the gradient overlay over the 'postImageView' but as you can see, I've decided to arbitrarily set the width and height of the 'maskedView' to 400. Ideally, **I'd like to set the width and height to those of the 'postImageView'** but when I try to do that using the code below, the gradient overlay no longer shows up.

```
let postImageViewSize: CGRect = postImageView.bounds
let postImageViewWidth = postImageViewSize.width
let postImageViewHeight = postImageViewSize.height

let maskedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.5, width: postImageViewWidth, height: postImageViewHeight))
```

**Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong here?**

Comment: where are you calling this code from?  If the postimageview isn't completely initialised and dispalyed, then it's bounds won't be accurate.  You could put a breakpoint on the final statement and inspect the properties to see if they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: This function is called right after addSubview(postImageView) in the init function. Could it be that the postImageView just wasn't completely initialized when the function runs (even though it's placed after addSubview(postImageView)?

Comment: Addressing bounds within an init is always risky as there's no guarantee that the view will have finished drawing.  I'll drop my approach (not sure if it's the best!0 into the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Using a view's `bounds` within an initialiser is always pot luck as there's no guarantee that the view will be fully drawn when the bounds property is accessed.  A better approach is to override the layer's `layoutSublayers(of:)` method.

```
   override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
      super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
      gradientMaskLayer.frame = self.bounds
   }
```

Assuming your layer is created within a view, the view automatically assigns itself as the layer's delegate, thu sproviding the `layoutSublayers(of:)` method that you can then override as above.  If you are not creaing it within a view then you will have to set up the delegate functionality yourself.  I'd recommend doing in within a view :-)

Answer (score 0):

Flanker is actually right. So go ahead and set the width and height to those of the 'postImageView'.

```
func configureGradientOverlay() {
    
    let postImageViewSize: CGRect = postImageView.bounds
    let postImageViewWidth = postImageViewSize.width
    let postImageViewHeight = postImageViewSize.height
  
    let maskedView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0.5, width: postImageViewWidth, height: postImageViewHeight))
    maskedView.backgroundColor = .black

    maskedView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
    postImageView.addSubview(maskedView)
}
```

And then call as well the `configureGradientOverlay` in `layoutSublayers`.

```
override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
    super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
    
  let gradientMaskLayer = CAGradientLayer()
          gradientMaskLayer.frame = maskedView.bounds
          gradientMaskLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
          gradientMaskLayer.locations = [0, 0.4, 0.6, 0.99]

          maskedView.layer.mask = gradientMaskLayer
}
```

Voila!

EDIT (aside from the codes), the `postImageViewHeight` will be ZERO here, unless you calculate the height in `didLayoutSubviews()` or something.